# Creating a scheduled task for different users and battery mode off

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I've a python executable file that I've written. I would like to distribute it to other people. The exe will be on the fileserver and this exe file should work on 14:00 for all the users.

Firstly, I tried to put it into a batch file with the cmd code to create a scheduled task and  -schtask command-. The code is getting the directory into a variable and adding /program.exe and sending it to schtask command.

Problem is I can not set the option for working on battery mode in task scheduler with cmd.

Is there an alternative to CMD? As I understand, I can use powershell, but not sure how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So of everything you've posted, if we remove all of the bloat, you are asking, ”Is there a non cmd.exe method to trigger a scheduled task to run only when a networked computer is running without AC". That is hardly an on topic [[tag:batch-file]] or [[tag:cmd]] programming code issue, is it?

Comment: I believe, batch-file is a method of doing this. for instance a powershell code could be executed with batch file?

Comment: You said "Is there an alternative to CMD?", batch files are a list of commands run by CMD! It follows that batch files are not an alternative to CMD, does it not?